# Event handling in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have modified the `ControlTemplate` for a `TabItem` to have a close button for a tab. Following is my XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TabItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" CornerRadius="0,4,0,0">
        <Grid Name="Panel">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="10,2" />
            <Button x:Name="closeButton" Background="Transparent"  Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click" Width="15" Height="15" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,2,0">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="backgroundEllipse" />
                            <Path x:Name="ButtonPath" Margin="3" Stroke="{StaticResource NormalForegroundBrush}" StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeStartLineCap="Square" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <PathGeometry>
                                        <PathGeometry.Figures>
                                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                                <LineSegment Point="25,25" />
                                            </PathFigure>
                                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,25">
                                                <LineSegment Point="25,0" />
                                            </PathFigure>
                                        </PathGeometry.Figures>
                                    </PathGeometry>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="backgroundEllipse" Property="Fill"  Value="{StaticResource HoverBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="ButtonPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource HoverForegroundBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In the above `ControlTemplate`, I want to handle the click event in XAML itself, i.e, make the tab item hidden when this is clicked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to just have the TabItems Visibility set to Hidden/Collapsed, or do you want to actually remove it from the TabControl? Either way, I don't think that that is possible to achieve in just XAML, event handlers are always written in code behind.

Comment: I just want to toggle visibility

Comment: There are 2 possible solutions: either use the ToggleButton, like Saman suggested in his answer, or create a storyboard for Button.Clicked trigger and set the Visibility to Hidden there.

Comment: Take exactly what you've got, but a) (per @Saman) change the Button to a ToggleButton, and b) Add this to the `ToggleButton`: `IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`. `IsEnabled` then controls their visibility. Set `IsEnabled` back to true to reveal them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a togglebutton instead of button as your closebutton, then on it's checked trigger set tabitem visibility to hidden/collapsed.